# What's the difference between alignItems and alignSelf in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to understand the FlexBox implementation on React Native and find it very unfortunate that [Facebook's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) doesn't provide any info at all on what the individual properties mean. They only name the ones that they have implemented without further documentation...

I love the [Flexbox in 5](http://flexboxin5.com/) tutorial, it does an amazing job in explaining the most important FlexBox properties. However, there is no mention of the `alignSelf` property there and I also didn't find documentation about this one elsewhere...

Can someone explain (maybe even demonstrate visually) what the difference between the two is? I also appreciate links to any resources that explain the React Native FlexBox properties in more detail and provide some guidance in using them.

Comment: align-self and align-items are NOT react properties. They are a part of native CSS properties that go under `flexbox`. React native just provides you a js/dom api to access those.

Comment: `align-items` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: `align-self` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`alignItems` and `alignSelf` have the same functionality per se. The only difference being, `alignItems` applies the alignment on to it's **children** while `alignSelf` applies the alignment to **itself**. This is useful when you want to change the alignment of one child.

Here is an illustration from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

[image]

The above happens when the container has a style `alignItems:'flex-start'`

[image]

This happens when the container has the style `alignItems:'flex-start'` and the third child has the style `alignSelf:'flex-end`

Answer (score 2):

`alignSelf` can override the `alignItems` value for specific items.